# Am I integrating AdColony incorrectly?

Tags: swift, adcolony

After doing many hours of research and tested implementation I have found myself back at Stack Overflow. I have Admob Installed which works perfectly. However, I am trying to integrate AdColony into my app to get more impressions. I have create many accounts to try and solve this issue but for some reason my dashboard on AdColony continues to say SDK not integrated and Market ID not provided. I have correctly installed AdColony so I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong. No ads are being generated from my AdColony account. If someone could explain (without just sending me back to the docs WHICH ARE OUTDATED) I would greatly appreciate it. I think it might have to do with the Market ID.

Comment: I found this at:https://support.adcolony.com/helpdesk/web-dashboard-publisher-apps-zones-setup/       "Market ID not provided: The app’s store bundle ID has not been linked yet. Its store bundle ID will be automatically linked when we see impressions from 100 unique devices in the app."

Answer (score 0):

this from adcolony website:

Market ID not provided
Your app’s market ID will be set up automatically through your integration of the AdColony SDK.  To complete this process, your app must play impressions for a few days, if you are seeing more than 100 views from unique devices in your app’s dashboard, please contact support and we’ll review the app.
https://support.adcolony.com/helpdesk/app-status-in-web-dashboard/